# finding user id accessing my system using C#

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm developing a small application using C# that

- will run as a service
- will monitor (uses FileSystemWatcher) and log the changes made to files under a certain directory say C:\

I'm able to achieve the above things, below are the things i'm looking for pointers/suggestions

- if some one accesses (with or without admin previlege) my machine ( using Run command and passing input as \ \mysystemname\C$) and creates/deletes/modifies files under the directory, then how should i can get the user id of the account.  For example if i use System.Environment.UserName then it gives my user name.

Is it possible to monitor the above scenario if so can any one provide me pointers.

Comment: I guess you could enable auditing for the target folder and then look for audit events in the Windows event log. To do this "properly" you may need to write a file system filter driver - I doubt even attempting to do that in C# is a good idea...

Comment: You can only detect said activity if Windows logs said activity and I don't believe it does.  Windows does not keep track of who creates or modifies a file.

Answer (score 0):

If this is tracking remote file access to a shared drive, you might want to check out this open source project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62357/Monitoring-Access-to-Your-Shared-Files-on-Network

Browsing through the code I don't see exactly how the username is retrieved, but the app looks to have the features you need.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It helps in displaying the live connection, but doesn't address the file modification or deletion by a user.